# how to perform such an expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am checking an explicit expansion for 
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j>1/2}(2j+1)^2\ln\left(\frac{j(2j-1)}{(j+1)(2j+3)}\right)=\sum_{j>1/2}\left[-6j-3-\frac{3}{2j}+\frac{3}{4j^2}+...\right],$$
where $j$ takes integer and semi-integer values. I believe in the expansion, $j$ is taken to be a large number.

I am sorry for asking such a pure computational question. But I do have tried to make it by myself but failed to arrive the correct result. Thus I am curious to see the potential skills for performing such algebras.

I do checked this expansion by mathematica and indeed got agreement. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I guess the $\sum_{j>1/2}$ is quite irrelevant$^{(*)}$, it is enough to ask why the asymptotic expansion $$\frac{1}{2}(2j+1)^2 \log\frac{j(2j-1)}{(j+1)(2j+3)}=-6j-3-\frac{3}{2j}+\frac{3}{4j^2}+\ldots $$ holds for every $j>1/2$, and that is just a Laurent series.

Comment: $(*)$ Also because $\sum_{j>1/2}6j, \sum_{j>1/2}3, \sum_{j>1/2}\frac{3}{2j}$ are all divergent.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $x=\frac 1j$ and consider $$A=\frac{j (2 j-1)}{(j+1) (2 j+3)}=\frac{2-x}{3 x^2+5 x+2}$$Start with the long division or Taylor series around $x=0$; then $$A=1-3 x+6 x^2-\frac{21 x^3}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Taylor again $$\log(A)=-3 x+\frac{3 x^2}{2}-\frac{3 x^3}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ I am sure that you can easily take it from here.